How to replace a multiline block of code by another one delimited by specified char
Here is a generic header of bash files.
#!/bin/bash
#
#####################################
#                                   #
#   {config_}                       #
#                                   #
#   ~/this_is_a very_very_very_long_filename
#                                   #
#   INSTALL VERSION                 #
#                                   #
#   §2023_06_18§                    #
#                                   #
#   ¨version:50-0-1¨                #
#                                   #
#   ɸmodif_version:1-0-3ɸ           #
#                                   #
#####################################
#
# Applications configuration files
#
########################################################
#
#
#
########################################################
#

I want to replace :
        §2023_06_18§                    #
    #                                   #
    #   ¨version:39-0-10¨

by
        §2024_07_18§                    #
    #                                   #
    #   ¨version:43-1-00¨

The start of block is the first char '§'
The end of block is the second '¨'
I know very little about sed or Awk; but Awk seems to me more understandable.

Your shown data contains no §2023_06_18§.

please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment : 'Awk or Sed: Replace text between special characters (delimiters) (3 answers)'  has nothing to do with my question which is about multi-lines search/replace.

As I said, I know very little about sed or Awk; so I have no code to show because I did not know how to know how to tackle the problem. Sorry.

I added a second duplicate. If you are not willing to learn the very basics of the language you are asking about, Stack Overflow might not be for you.

X/Y problem. The date and version tags were almost certainly generated by some software. That's where you want to set the new version. You don't want to be editing generated content, unless it's a conscious decision by the entire team/organization to permanently abandon the generator. Otherwise someone will use the generator again and clobber your changes.

@Kaz These headers are from my responsibility and are not (yet) generated by some software..

[ I assume you really just wish to change the first instance in the file of the date and version strings, and that the rest of the "block" remains unchanged. If that is not the case, please clarify the question with more thorough example. ]
awk -v d='2024_07_18' -v v='version:43-1-00' '
    d && sub(/§[0-9_]+§/,         "§"d"§") {d=0}
    v && sub(/¨version:[0-9-]+¨/, "¨"v"¨") {v=0}
    1
' originalfile >newfile


initialise d and v
for every line:

if d(v) is set, try to substitute; unset on success
print the line




adjust the two regex if the values can contain different characters than those shown in the question

you could also consider diff + patch

It would be nice if you can explain  d && sub(/§[0-9_]+§/,         "§"d"§") {d=_}

@jhnc That seems to work on two tests. Thank you for helping

@jcdole "if d(v) is set, try to substitute; unset on success" was supposed to be the explanation. I've changed the assignment to d=0 per Ed's comment

@EdMorton another subtlety would be that if d or v are initially set to the empty string, or a number equivalent to zero, the code breaks. I initially wrote the code with separate flag variables !doned,doned=1, etc, which while feeling wordier would probably have been better in multiple ways

@jhnc true, but I think you're probably safe in assuming neither would be 0 or empty.
